# locate extended attributes

Tags: linux, wrapper, patch, locate, xattr

Is there a simple way to write a kind of wrapper script or patch for updatedb (or locate) such that locate can find user defined extended attributes (tags) (suppose in an ext3 filesystem, mounted with user_xattr option), too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as locate is quite specialize to search a list of pathnames, what you'd want would be a new program that like updatedb scans the file system and collects (pathname, xattr, value) and then provides a way like locate to search this database by xattr and value from which it returns pathnames